# Joining two lists in this order

Tags: python

```
list1 = [2 3 4]
list2 = [0 1 2 3]
```

desired output / or similar

```
(2,0) (2,1) (2,2) (2,3) (3,0) (3,1) (3,2) (3,3) (4,0)
```

i.e. for every val in list1, iterate through list2 before moving to next val in list1

I might be here for the next day trying to do it :/  ... tyty

Comment: What have you tried so far? The approach you are describing seems to be in the right direction...

Comment: So nested for loop would be a great solution, like mentioned in the comments by Pingu and timgeb already. Did that solve the problem? If not, please spend a little more time improving the original post with your findings.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/533905/get-the-cartesian-product-of-a-series-of-lists

Answer (score 0):

You can create an array of tuples which corresponds to each unique link between the values in list1 and list2

```
linked_values=[]
for i in list1:
    for j in list2:
        linked_values.append((i,j))
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the standard library function [`itertools.product()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) for this.

However, for trivial cases, you might as well use this one-liner:

```py
output = [(i, j) for i in list1 for j in list2]
```